# Can your iPad show your position on map feature if in range of a WiFi signal without a password to that WiFi?

Tags: ipados, geolocation

Can your iPad show your position on map feature if in range of a WiFi signal *but* without a password to that WiFi?

Can Google Maps work etc…, if you are or not near a WiFi signal and without/with a password as well?

Comment: Is this about an iPad with cellular/SIM, or about a WiFi-only iPad? Also, do you assume that the map material itself is already available on the device and can be used by Maps without being online?

Comment: There is no need to login to wifi, Maps is simply using a triagulation between 'seen' SSID and signal strength. This gives you a large 'circle of confusion' on the map, that shrinks as you move or get GPS data

Answer (score 0):

Google maps uses data & GPS location. You can download a physical area for offline mode. Meaning Google maps can give directions while offline in that area. So the next question is do all iPad models include GPS, it seems they may not. iPads can have cellular data so can get Google maps data if you have that model & a data plan with a cellular phone company. So yes certain iPads can use Google maps while not on Wi-Fi.

https://www.apple.com/ipad-10.2/specs/

Comment: One assumes that original poster only has a WiFi connection and cellular data is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

> if in range of a WiFi signal but without a password to that WiFi?

If you have *some* kind of data connection, probably yes – e.g. on Android, the "Google Location Services" component will collect nearby Wi-Fi SSIDs with their signal strength and will query Google's geolocation database to give you an approximate location – and I believe Apple has a similar service as well.

(For Android apparently the "Street View" cars are gathering this information, and I *think* regular Android phones participate as well. Google has an API for this service (Chrome uses it to locate your laptop, which usually lacks GPS) and Mozilla has an [equivalent](https://location.services.mozilla.com/) service that Firefox uses.)

If you have no data connection whatsoever (no 3G/4G/5G), then no.

Comment: This answer is correct for iPad and iPhone.  Location based on WiFi is not as accurate as GPS, but it can work if GPS is not available.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_positioning_system